# Real Analysis, Folland Theorem 3.27 Properties of functions of Bounded Variation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Background Information:**

Taking $a = -\infty$ and considering the total variation as a function of $b$. To with $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we define $$T_F(x) = \sup\{\sum_{1}^{n}|F(x_j) - F(x_{j-1}|:n\in\mathbb{N},-\infty < x_0 < \ldots < x_n = x\}$$ $T_F$ is called the total variation of $F$.

We observe that the sums in the definition of $T_F$ are made bigger if the additional subdivision points $x_j$ are added. Hence, if $a < b$, the deinition of $T_F(b)$ is unaffected if we assume that $a$ is always one of the subdivision points. It follows that $$T_F(b) - T_F(a) = \sup\{\sum_{1}^{n}|F(x_j) - F(x_{j-1}|:n\in\mathbb{N},a = x_0 < \ldots < x_n = b\}$$
Thus $T_F$ is an increasing function with values in $[0,\infty]$. If $T_F(\infty) = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}T_F(x)$ is finite, we say that $F$ is of bounded variation on $\mathbb{R}$, and we denote the space of all such $F$ by $BV$.

More generally, the supremum on the right side is called the total variation of $F$ on $[a,b]$. It depends only on the values of $F$ on $[a,b]$, so we may define $BV([a,b])$ to be the set of all functions on $[a,b]$ whose total variation on $[a,b]$ is finite.

> Theorem 3.23 - Let $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be increasing, and let $G(x) = F(x^+)$.
>
> a.) The set of points at which $F$ is discontinuous is countable.
>
> b.) $F$ and $G$ are differentiable a.e., and $F' = G'$.
>
> 3.25 Examples:
>
> a.) If $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and increasing, then $F\in BV$ (in fact, $T_F(x) = F(x) - F(-\infty)$).
>
> b.) If $F,G\in BV$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$, then $aF + bG\in BV$.
>
> Lemma 3.26 - If $F\in BV$ is real-valued, then $T_F + F$ and $T_F - F$ are increasing.

**Question:**

> Theorem 3.27
>
> a.) If $F\in BV$ if and only if $Re F \in BV$ and $Im F \in BV$.
>
> b.) If $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then $F\in BV$ if and only if $F$ is the difference of two bounded increasing functions; for $F\in BV$ these functions may be taken to be $(\frac{1}{2}(T_F + F)$ and $\frac{1}{2}(T_F - F)$.
>
> c.) If $F\in BV$, then $F(x^+) = \lim_{y\searrow x}F(y)$ and $F(x^-) = \lim_{y\nearrow x}F(y)$ exists for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, as do $F(\pm\infty) = \lim_{y\rightarrow \pm\infty}F(y)$.
>
> d.) If $F\in BV$, the set of points at which $F$ is discontinuous is countable.
>
> e.) If $F\in BV$ and $G(x) = F(x^+)$, then $F'$ and $G'$ exist and are equal a.e.

Proof a.) I am sort of confused how I should show that $Re F \in BV$ and $Im F \in BV$ from just supposing $F\in BV$. I know that if $F\in BV$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}T_F(x) = T_F(\infty) < +\infty$. But I am not sure how to add the real and imaginary parts of $F$ to show that they are also of bounded variation.

Proof b.) Suppose $F\in BV$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}T_F(x) = T_F(\infty) < +\infty$ and from Example 3.25 we can write $$F = \frac{1}{2}(T_F + F) - \frac{1}{2}(T_F - F)$$

For the converse, I don't understand how if $F$ is taken to be the difference of these two increasing functions would should that $F\in BV$. What Folland does is refer back to the proof of Lemma 3.26 and states the inequalities for $x < y$ $$T_F(y) \pm F(y) \geq T_F(x) \pm F(x)$$ implies that $$|F(y) - F(x)| \leq T_F(y) - T_F(x) \leq T_F(\infty) - T_F(-\infty) < \infty$$ ok... so this shows that $F$ and $T_F\pm F$ is bounded. But how is Folland using the difference of $F$ to show that $F\in BV$?

For c,d,e Folland states that the result follows from a,b and Theorem 3.23. I can see how d and e may follow from Theorem 3.23 (not sure how to prove it though) but I don't see how the above results follow to prove c.

I am pretty lost with this theorem any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure why I got voted down twice, if there is something wrong with my question then I will glady edit it...

Comment: I'm not sure why, either. The problem is stated properly with good context, formatted and tagged correctly, and you made a reasonable effort and highlighted which parts you weren't sure about. So, it's better than the average MSE question, which admittedly is damning with faint praise :-)

Comment: @Bungo I downvoted because I disagree with the OP's apparent project to put a solution manual to Folland here or to ask about every single exercise / theorem in the book  - I think it's badly conceived and have commented to that effect in the past.

Comment: @T.Bongers I was unaware of that context. I have seen other Folland questions from the same OP but assumed he/she was self-studying and asking questions as they arose. I agree that this isn't the right venue for compiling a solutions manual.

Comment: @Bungo I'm not entirely sure if that's the goal, or if the OP just has so many difficulties / lack of background / lack of confidence that they need verification on every little detail of every theorem and exercise in Folland. Regardless, I don't think that this is an appropriate use of MSE. I haven't counted *precisely*, but I suspect that there are now over 100 questions from the OP following this exact format.

Comment: I down voted for essentially the same reason as T. Bongers.  You have so many questions from Folland's book, its going to be impossible to teach a course using that book unless you delete most of your questions.  Furthermore, math isn't learned by giving up on a question after 30 minutes to an hour. You need to spend time with the question, get an understanding of what it is asking, and why the answer is what the answer is. If you do that and find the answer, you will feel so much better about yourself afterwards.

Comment: Furthermore, I down voted because this is essentially a five-part question.  Choose one at a time.

Comment: @Wolfy Folland is a good book but it's terse and dense and not especially user-friendly. You might find it helpful to supplement it with another book. I think Cohn's [Measure Theory](https://www.amazon.com/Measure-Theory-Birkhäuser-Advanced-Lehrbücher/dp/1461469554/) is excellent, at the same level of sophistication but significantly easier to read. Another really nice book (for Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^d$) is Jones, [Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space](https://www.amazon.com/Lebesgue-Integration-Euclidean-Bartlett-Mathematics/dp/0763717088)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Theorem 3.27
>
> a.) If $F\in BV$ if and only if $Re F \in BV$ and $Im F \in BV$.
>
> b.) If $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then $F\in BV$ if and only if $F$ is the difference of two bounded increasing functions; for $F\in BV$ these functions may be taken to be $(\frac{1}{2}(T_F + F)$ and $\frac{1}{2}(T_F - F)$.
>
> c.) If $F\in BV$, then $F(x^+) = \lim_{y\searrow x}F(y)$ and $F(x^-) = \lim_{y\nearrow x}F(y)$ exist for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, as do $F(\pm\infty) = \lim_{y\rightarrow \pm\infty}F(y)$.
>
> d.) If $F\in BV$, the set of points at which $F$ is discontinuous is countable.
>
> e.) If $F\in BV$ and $G(x) = F(x^+)$, then $F'$ and $G'$ exist and are equal a.e.

**Proof**:

**a.)** ($\Rightarrow$)
Suppose $F\in BV$. Then we have 
\begin{align*}
T_{ReF}(x) &= \sup\{\sum_{1}^{n}|ReF(x_j) - ReF(x_{j-1})|:n\in\mathbb{N},-\infty < x_0 < \ldots < x_n = x\} \leq \\
& \leq \sup\{\sum_{1}^{n}|F(x_j) - F(x_{j-1})|:n\in\mathbb{N},-\infty < x_0 < \ldots < x_n = x\} = \\
& = T_F(x)
\end{align*}
So, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $ T_{ReF}(x) \leq  T_F(x)$ . So, $ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}T_{ReF}(x) \leq \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}T_F(x)<+\infty$. So  $Re F \in BV$.

In exactly the same way we prove that $Im F \in BV$.

($\Leftarrow$)
Now suppose $Re F \in BV$ and  $Im F \in BV$. Then, we have 
\begin{align*}
T_F(x) &= \sup\{\sum_{1}^{n}|F(x_j) - F(x_{j-1})|:n\in\mathbb{N},-\infty < x_0 < \ldots < x_n = x\}  \leq \\
& \leq  \sup\{\sum_{1}^{n}(|ReF(x_j) - ReF(x_{j-1})|+ |ImF(x_j) - ImF(x_{j-1})|):n\in\mathbb{N},-\infty < x_0 < \ldots < x_n = x\} \leq \\
& \leq  \sup\{\sum_{1}^{n}|ReF(x_j) - ReF(x_{j-1})|:n\in\mathbb{N},-\infty < x_0 < \ldots < x_n = x\}+ \\
& \phantom{\leq\:}+ \sup\{\sum_{1}^{n}|ImF(x_j) - ImF(x_{j-1})|:n\in\mathbb{N},-\infty < x_0 < \ldots < x_n = x\} = \\
& = T_{ReF}(x)+T_{ImF}(x)
\end{align*}
So, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $T_F(x) \leq  T_{ReF}(x)+T_{ImF}(x)$.
So $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}T_F(x)\leq \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}T_{ReF}(x) +  \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}T_{ImF}(x)<+\infty$. So $F\in BV$.

**b.)** Let $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

($\Rightarrow$)
Suppose  $F\in BV$. By lemma 3.26, $T_F + F$ and $T_F - F$ are increasing. So $\frac{1}{2} (T_F + F)$ and $\frac{1}{2} (T_F - F)$ are increasing and we have 
$$ F = \frac{1}{2} (T_F + F) -$\frac{1}{2} (T_F - F)$$

Now, to complete this part of the proof we must show that $\frac{1}{2} (T_F + F)$ and $\frac{1}{2} (T_F - F)$ are bounded.

Since $F\in BV$, we have that $T_F$ is bounded, so all need is to prove that $F$ is a bounded function. This is a consequence of Lemma 3.26.

Note that, since  $T_F + F$ and $T_F - F$ are increasing functions, we have, for $y>x$, 
$$T_F(y) \pm F(y) \geq T_F(x) \pm F(x)$$
So 
$$T_F(y)- T_F(x) \geq \mp F(y)\pm F(x)$$
which means 
$$T_F(y)- T_F(x) \geq |F(y) - F(x)|$$
So we have 
$$|F(y) - F(x)| \leq T_F(y)- T_F(x) \leq  T_F(+\infty)- T_F(-\infty) < \infty$$
So $F$ is a bounded function.

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose  $F$ is the difference of two bounded increasing functions. It is a direct consequence of 3.25 a.) and b.) that $F\in BV$.

Now, let us prove items **c.)** , **d.)** and **e.)** .

Suppose $F\in BV$. Then by item a.),  $Re F \in BV$ and $Im F \in BV$. By item b.), we have that $Re F$ is  the difference of two bounded increasing functions $g_1$ and $g_2$ and also  $Im F$ is  the difference of two bounded increasing functions $g_3$ and $h_4$. So, we have that $F=(g_1-g_2)+i(g_3-g_4)$.

Since $g_1$, $g_2$ , $g_3$ and $h_4$ are increasing functions, then, for $i=1,\ldots 4$, 
$$ g_i(x^+) = \lim_{y\searrow x}g_i(y) \textrm{ and } g_i(x^-) = \lim_{y\nearrow x}g_i(y) \quad \textrm{ exist and are finite, for all } x\in\mathbb{R}$$

And, since $g_1$, $g_2$ , $g_3$ and $h_4$ are bounded increasing functions, then, for $i=1,\ldots 4$,
$$g_i(\pm\infty) = \lim_{y\rightarrow \pm\infty}g_i(y)<\infty$$

Since $F=(g_1-g_2)+i(g_3-g_4)$, we have that $F(x^+) = \lim_{y\searrow x}F(y)$ and $F(x^-) = \lim_{y\nearrow x}F(y)$ exist and are finite, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, as do $F(\pm\infty) = \lim_{y\rightarrow \pm\infty}F(y)<\infty$.
So we have proved c.)

Now, by 3.23 a.) we have that, for  $i=1,\ldots 4$, the set of points at which $g_i$ is discontinuous is countable. Since $F=(g_1-g_2)+i(g_3-g_4)$, we have that 
the set of points at which $F$ is discontinuous is countable. So we have proved d.)

Now, define $G(x) = F(x^+)$ and, for  $i=1,\ldots 4$, define $h_i(x)=g_i(x^+)$. 
Then
$$G(x) = F(x^+)=(g_1(x^+)-g_2(x^+))+i(g_3(x^+)-g_4(x^+))= (h_1(x)-h_2(x))+i(h_3(x)-h_4(x))$$
Now, by 3.23 b.) we have that, for  $i=1,\ldots 4$,  $g_i'$ and $h_i'$ exist and are equal a.e.. So, since  $F=(g_1-g_2)+i(g_3-g_4)$ and $G= (h_1-h_2)+i(h_3-h_4)$, we have that $F'$ and $G'$ exist and are equal a.e.
So we have proved e.).

Comment: when you say $T_{ReF}(x)$ you mean the variation of F in any $ x\in\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: @AaronMartinez  Yes. When I write $ T_{ReF}(x)$,  I mean the total variation of $ReF$ (the real part of $F$) at any arbitrary $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: got it , thanks

Answer (score 1):

For (a), use the fact that for any complex number $z$, we have the inequality $\max\{|\text{Re}z|,|\text{Im}z|\} \leq |z| \leq |\text{Re}z| + |\text{Im}z|$.

For the converse direction of (b), write $F = I - D$ where $I$ and $D$ are bounded and increasing. Then if $x_0 < x_1 < \ldots x_n$, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}|F(x_k)-F(x_{k-1})|& = \sum_{k=1}^{n}|I(x_k) - D(x_k) - I(x_{k-1}) + D(x_{k-1})|\\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}|I(x_k) - I(x_{k-1})| + \sum_{k=1}^{n}|D(x_k) - D(x_{k-1})| \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n}(I(x_k) - I(x_{k-1})) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}(D(x_k) - D(x_{k-1}))\\
&= (I(x_n) - I(x_0)) + (D(x_n) - D(x_0)) \\
&\leq \lim_{x \to \infty}I(x) - \lim_{x \to -\infty}I(x) + \lim_{x \to \infty}D(x) - \lim_{x \to -\infty}D(x)
\end{aligned}$$
The limits on the RHS exist and are finite since $I$ and $D$ are increasing and bounded.

For (c), note that a step discontinuity is the only kind of discontinuity possible in an increasing function; in particular this means that the left-hand and right-hand limits exist at all points. By (b), the same is true of any real-valued BV function, and therefore by (a), the same is true of the real and imaginary components of $F$.

For (d), note that by (a), the real and imaginary parts of $F$ have bounded variation. As these are real-valued, example 3.25(a) shows that each is the difference of two increasing functions. Now $F$ cannot be discontinuous at a point $x$ unless one of these four increasing functions is discontinuous at $x$. Since each increasing function is continuous except possibly on a countable set, the same is true of $F$, because the union of finitely many countable sets is countable.

For (e), again decompose $F$ into real and imaginary components, and then decompose each component into the difference of two increasing functions, then do the same for $G$, then apply 3.23(b) to each of the four pairs of increasing functions.